# How can I change in main activity android few buttons in one loop?

Tags: java, android

I have 9 buttons in android xml btn1 - btn9.

How can changed thier status ( enable or disable ) or ather attributes in one loop .

Instead of writing btn1.setEnabled(false) 9 times I want to do it with one loop.

How Can I do it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use an array of buttons.

Comment: You want to change all of them to have same state? for example if one is false, then all are false? Or you want to pass the value for every button? Can you elaborate the question more?

Comment: Hi - I want to set all false at one loop